# Stop additional workflow emails

Tags: 2013, workflow, send-email

I have created a basic workflow which sends an email to a selected user.

I don't want any additional emails sent to the user if for example the list is edited.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which type of workflow you created? Designer workflow? What are the triggers for your workflow? Can you please add any screenshot of the workflow actions you used?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your current workflow is set to trigger on item update, you can change your trigger so that the workflow will only run on item creation.  This way the workflow will only fire once, when the item is created, instead of every time the item is edited.

Comment: Thanks Josh, as I'm very new at this. Could you explain how this is done?